# Cannot convert value of type NSNumber to expected argument type NSNumber

Tags: swift, generic-programming

I am getting the error in the title when trying to use the argument of a generic function inherited from a base class

Base class:

```
BaseBottomBar: UIView {
    ...
    func formatDetailText<T>(value: T...) {
        assertionFailure("You shouldn't be using this base class")
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
NewTicketBottomBar: BaseBottomBar {

    override func formatDetailText<NSNumber>(value: NSNumber...) {
        let priceAsCurrencyString = NumberFormatter.currencyFormatter.string(from: value[1]) //Error on this line
        assert(priceAsCurrencyString != nil, "The price cannot be nil")
        let newTicketText = String(format: "%4.0f", value[0]) + " / TOTAL : " + priceAsCurrencyString!
        detailLabel.text = newTicketText
    }
}
```

[image: Cannot convert value of type NSNumber to expected argument type NSNumber]

I guess I have my base method prototype wrong in some way but I can't see how.

I wasn't using a generic method in the beginning and the prototype was the following:

```
func formatDetailText(value: Double...) {
    ...
    let priceAsCurrencyString = NumberFormatter.currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value[1]))
    ...
}
```

And this was working fine

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you want to make it generic you should use Numeric, BinaryInteger of FloatingPoint protocols. If you need to use NSNumber there is no need to make it generic. `func formatDetailText(value: NSNumber)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I thought I needed it because this method is meant to be overridden in subclasses but the bottom bar sometimes displays text instead of figures, that's why Numeric protocols won't do in my situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to think that

```
override func formatDetailText<NSNumber>(value: NSNumber...) {
```

resolves the generic `<T>` in the overridden method as NSNumber. It doesn't. It merely introduces a different name for the generic; NSNumber here is not the NSNumber class, it's just another generic placeholder name, exactly like T (in fact, it *is* T by another name).

So naturally, when you try to use this placeholder where an NSNumber is expected in NumberFormatter's `string(from:)`, the compiler turns around and says, "Dude [the compiler is from California, this is how it talks], I have no reason to think that your placeholder called "NSNumber" is in fact NSNumber."

You need to give it a reason to think that. What you probably mean is

```
override func formatDetailText<T>(value: T...) where T : NSNumber {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I works for NSNumber and I have a better understanding of how the swift compiler works :) I'd like it to take arguments of type `String` or `Double` if I can but they are structs and not classes is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Or should I make the generic type inherit from NSString instead if I want a string and NSNumber in the case of a number ?

Comment: The whole use case does not seem to me appropriate for a generic. But that’s irrelevant. I answered the compiler question. What you are trying to do and how to do it is a completely different question.

Comment: Thanks @matt, basically I have a bottom bar in my UI that needs to display information about the current state of the application such as prices or strings. As the design of the bar never changes, I wanted to be able to reuse the same view class and just override the method that displays the information. The problem I faced was that sometimes you have numbers, others you have just text. So in my sense, I needed to make a generic to be able to pass any parameter I wanted and leave the responsibility to display the information to the view class.

Comment: I don’t see why. To me it sounds like two method overloads. Just like http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_overloading One version takes a String, one version takes a number, done.  Easy and short. No generic, no subclass, no nothing. But, as I say, this discussion is inappropriate. If you feel like discussing what you should have been doing, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code isn't saying that the parameter must be an `NSNumber`. It's saying that it takes a generic type that you want to call `NSNumber`, just like you're using `T` above.

The error message is because there is no guarantee to the compiler that the generic type called `NSNumber` is a real `NSNumber` instance. You could pass a string to it for all it knows.

Your override should look like this

```
override func formatDetailText<T: NSNumber>(value: T...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it boils down to the same answer provided by @matt in different semantics :) I upvoted your answer too as it answered my question :)